# How to display "Please Wait" while GPO startup script is running?

Tags: script, batch, boot, group-policy, user-interface

I have a GPO that calls a batch file as a startup script (`Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Startup`) which takes a moment to finish what it's supposed to do.

I would like the batch file to finish before users are allowed to log in.  Is there any way to cause Windows to display the usual `Please Wait` message instead of `Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to log on` until the batch file terminates?

Answer (score 2):

Enable the gpo:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon\Run logon scripts synchronously

I believe this will also display 'Running startup scripts ... ' while they are loading.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to set the "System\Scripts\Run startup scripts asynchronously" to "Disabled".   The logon scripts setting applies after users log in, and the OP is referring to computer startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your GPO to run logon scripts synchronously.